# Competitor websites in the "recent" results for a Google search on my business name

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, keyword-stuffing

I try to keep aware of my online presence with things like [Google Alerts](https://www.google.co.za/alerts) & checking for mention of my business name [within the past 24 hours](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en) etc.

Recently I noticed two competing websites appear for my business name search (we don't manufacture any branded products, so it's not the case of them being relevant at all). I thought perhaps that they may be stuffing our keywords into their website, but at a glance of page source inspection, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Why would Google show search results for direct competitors on my brand name (**not AdWords**), is this regular behaviour or could something fishy be going on here?

Note: This only seems to appear when narrowing down the results to the past 24 hour period.